# Where can I find backgrounds for my poster?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, vector, corel-draw

I'm designing a 3'x2' flex poster for my startup. I'm a long time GIMP user but this is the first time I'm designing poster for printing (Vector graphics).

Coming to the design. It's pretty simple. Just my Logo, Company Name, Phone No on a white background. It pretty much looks like `Microsoft Word 2010 splash screen` without the Golden yellow colored background design. But its just this background that makes it looks beautiful.

[image: Microsoft Word 2010 splash screen]
 [image: Microsoft Word starter splash screen]

I'm looking for similar (exactly same would be ideal :) vector graphic art to add it to my poster. Just this one addition would change the look & feel of it. Can any one tell me where can I get designs like these?

Comment: If it looks exactly the same, you're opening yourself up to a cease and desist due to copyright infringement.

Comment: http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-3832819-blue-waves.php

Comment: Do you definitely need it to be vector art?

Comment: @e100: Yeah! I guess. As I said its first time I'm working with these things. Do the designers use 3'x2' raster images? Are they even available?

Comment: Well, billboards use raster images. Resolution can be very low when you're looking at something from further away. You could create that as a vector image, but it might be tricky to get the out-of-focus look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As DA01 wisely points out, don't make it exactly the same. A gradient per se isn't a trademark, but if it looks too similar they'll send the sharks after you.

That said, iStock has some ideas to start with:

http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-photo-5503907-soft-green.php?st=fdbf392

http://www.istockphoto.com/stock-illustration-4615159-abstract-swoosh-background.php?st=53b3e08

I searched for "gradient," but "swoosh" might get you some results as well.

Comment: +1 Thanks for telling me the terms you searched for. :)